# Google AdSense "Valuable Inventory: No Content", on a homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads, adsense

I run a gaming site where people can see statistics for weapons in the game (fortnite). The site's homepage that i made is mostly made up of images that link to pages that show the statistics for a weapon. I will link the website so that you guys can get a better idea of what i'm working with, http://fortnitegunstatistics.com. I sent an application to Google Adsense hoping that i could run some ads on my site. However, it was rejected for "Valuable Inventory: No Content". I thought that this meant that i don't have enough content, however i found out that people would get "Valuable Inventory: Insufficient Content". I looked it up and found that most people were putting ads on login pages, but it is the homepage for me.

Does anyone have an idea of what i should do to get around this error? I am willing to make any changes needed to my homepage, because i would assume my homepage is the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309580/a-google-adsense-violation-valuable-inventory-no-content-for-my-homepage

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images and links don't make up enough content for Google to index.  I recommend adding a paragraph of commentary for each weapon as to WHY you think it's a significant weapon.  That commentary will count as indexible content and will add value to your site.  Remember that Google indexes the text on your site to determine the category of ads it should serve, as well as the value of the site.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I think i'm going to add the name of all weapons when they hovered over, and i am going to make a description for each weapon category when a checkbox type of botton is clicked. Would Google see the text on hover and the text when a botton is clicked? I'm not sure if Google looks at the code or the site itself.

Comment: Googlebot is smart enough to see text now, even when injected with Javascript.  Don't forget to make sure you have a description and keywords meta tag in your header. :)